# SQLCipher - Opening an encrypted database on desktop

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm experimenting with SQLCipher on Android.  I wrote a small app that created a database with one table and a few records on the emulator.  Then, I pulled the database from the emulator onto my desktop.  I've looked at the SQLCipher documentation, but I can't figure out how to actually decrypt the database on the desktop so I can query its contents.  I wanted to make sure I actually inserted records.  What's the easiest process to get access to the records?  Thanks.

Comment: I do not see any evidence of a pre-compiled command-line `sqlite3` or anything like that based on SQLCipher. In theory, you can compile it yourself. You might also wish to inquire on the SQLCipher support group: http://groups.google.com/group/sqlcipher/topics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the build instructions on the [SQLCipher site](http://sqlcipher.net/introduction/) will allow you to compile a command line version of the sqlite3 command line shell. If you are on windows you can also purchase one of the [windows binary distributions](http://sqlcipher.net/downloads/), which both include a pre-compiled windows binary shell.

Comment: Is this different from the sqlite3 command line tool that's included in the tools folder of the Android SDK?

Comment: yes, the version distributed with the Android SDK doesn't include the SQLCipher extensions, so it is unable to access an encrypted database. You need to use a sqlite3 command shell that was built to include the SQLCipher extension.